# Not able to save settings when writing a Windows Sidebar Gadget with write or writeString

Tags: javascript, html, windows, settings, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm writing a simple Windows Gadget, but I can't seem to get the settings to save when using this functions. Here's some of the code that should get the task done, but still won't work:

```
var mySettings = new botanicallileo();

function botanicallileo()
{ 
    this.kitID = "";
    this.load = loadSettings;
    this.save = saveSettings;
}
function saveSettings()
{
     System.Gadget.Settings.writeString("test", "true");
     System.Gadget.Settings.writeString("kitID", this.kitID);
}

function settingsClosing(event)
{
    if (event.closeAction == event.Action.commit)
    {
        mySettings.save();
    }
}
```

I must be missing something very important but I can't seem to find what it is. I know the settings aren't saving because I can check the .ini file, and nothing seems to pop up, while with other gadgets the new variables do appear and get saved in the file. Help will be appreciated.

Note: the settings "test" is just that, a test to see if anything was getting written at all. Needless to say it's not getting written.